# Building docker images from Apache Airflow

Tags: docker, airflow, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-composer

I'm having a hard time Googling for this. What I'm trying to do is have an Airflow task running on Google Cloud Composer that will download data from BigQuery, massage the data, then issue a `docker build` command to build a Docker image, then send it to Google Container Registry and do other stuff thereafter.

My question: How do I get a Docker engine in Cloud Composer so I can run `docker build` from my Airflow task?

Comment: Did you take a look in the BashOperator? (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/bash.html)  Let me know if its a possibility for you

Comment: The bash operator does allow me to run `docker build`, but the docker engine is required for that to work (else, it'll say `command not found`), which is more what I'm asking. After researching some more, it looks like what I really need for this is Google Cloud Build instead of Airflow.